# What happens when I run out of resources on EC2 or GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, resources, amazon-ec2, cloud

I`ve recently read [this article](http://www.btcnn.com/2011/08/third-largest-bitcoin-exchange-loses.html) about a user losing data on EC2 when dealing with low resources on EC2. This made me wonder if there is any documentation of what will happen to apps running on EC2 or GAE when they run out of resources. Do they terminate, are frozen until the next cycle or some payment going through, or perhaps something else? How can one mitigate the risks associated with the services running out of resources (aside from, obviously, paying more)?

Comment: You need to separate your question into two one for EC2 and one for GAE.

Comment: Also, the developers in the case of that article were spectacularly stupid. Not only did they not take any backups of their most valuable asset, but they relied solely on a storage medium that's clearly documented as ephemeral.

Comment: This had nothing to do with EC2 or "running out of resources"  It has to do with gross negligence.  This guy was basically storing cash in RAM, on a server with a sketchy power supply and a toddler nearby who likes to push reset buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GAE just stops giving you the depleted resource.
EC2 is "pay as you go" for some resources (network, uptime, etc...) - so you just get billed more. Some other (cpu / memory) are predefined and just serve as much as they can, like "regular" cpu and memory.